# Turn off/stop browser camera in my sample react video call application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, websocket, webrtc, kurento

I am developing a video chat web application using react.js and kurento utils SDK for the media server. The problem is that the camera/light is still ON even after the video call is ended.The camera stops only for the first time and the problem occurs only from the second call.

```
  let stream = videoElem.srcObject;
  let tracks = stream.getTracks();

  tracks.forEach(function(track) {
    track.stop();
  });

  videoElem.srcObject = null;
}
```

I tried every possible ways to solve this issue and the above code is what i used for stopping camera.Is this a problem with react.js?

Comment: did you find solution?

Answer (score 3):

Can you try stopping individual video and audio track as webrtc APIs 
e.g.

```
mediaStream.getAudioTracks()[0].stop();
mediaStream.getVideoTracks()[0].stop();
```

Comment: I tried this too.But it only works for the first call then the camera light is ON even after the call is end.

Comment: How to turn it on again?

Answer (score 0):

You must have more than one stream instances.
What you can do is to have a single instance of stream, you can store it on redux or context and call it when you need it accordingly.